# Rust variable in struct for TcpStream to be used in multiple funcions

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a struct that uses `std::net::TcpStream` to read/write to a socket.
I got test code working in a function but when trying to split the code up into multiple functions (`read()`, `write()`, etc.) I would like to share the `TcpStream` object.
In other languages I would create a class `TcpStream` variable (init to `null`) and then have a `connect()` function set the variable to an object using `TcpStream::connect()`. Then I could use the class variable in other class functions. But I do not get this to work in Rust.
I have looked into `once_cell` and `lazy_static` but not getting anywhere.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
pub struct Connection<'a> {
  url:&'a str,
  conn: &TcpStream
}

impl Connection<'_> {

  pub fn new(url: &str) -> Connection {
    return Connection {
      url: url
    }
  }

  pub fn connect(&self) -> bool {
    self.conn = TcpStream::connect();
    return true;
  }

  pub fn write(&self, cmd : &str ) -> bool {
    self.conn.write(cmd);
    return true;
  }

  pub fn read() -> String {
    return self.conn.read();
  }
}

let my_connection = Connection::new("localhost:23");
```

Comment: You can greatly increase the chance of good answer by avoiding phrases like "But I do not get this to work" as the only explanation of what your actual problem is.

Comment: What would `write` and `read` do if `connect` was not called? Even if you return a sensible error, it doesn't make sense for them to be callable in the first place if you can avoid it. In Rust you normally either connect during the construction or allow the user to pass in the already-connected stream to a constructor.

Comment: If you are worried about shared ownership, clone the stream as many time as you need.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to turn your `TcpStream` into a `Singleton`. The best way to do this is with the `thread_local` macro.
The following is intended as a guideline only and does not contain any error handling:

```
pub struct Connection {
    url: String,
}

impl Connection {
    thread_local! {
         static MY_CONNECTION: RefCell<TcpStream> = RefCell::new(TcpStream::connect("localhost:23").expect("STREAM"));
    }

    pub fn new(url: &str) -> Connection {
        Self::MY_CONNECTION.with(|conn| {
            *conn.borrow_mut() = TcpStream::connect(url).expect("STREAM");
        });
        Connection {
            url: url.to_string(),
        }
    }

    pub fn connect(&self, to: &str) -> bool {
        Self::MY_CONNECTION
            .with(|conn| *conn.borrow_mut() = TcpStream::connect(to).expect("STREAM"));
        true
    }

    pub fn write(&self, cmd: &[u8]) -> bool {
        Self::MY_CONNECTION
            .with(|conn| conn.borrow_mut().write(cmd))
            .is_ok()
    }

    pub fn read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Option<usize> {
        Self::MY_CONNECTION
            .with(|conn| {
                let mut c = conn.borrow_mut();
                c.read(buf)
            })
            .ok()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=84eb33be15e426ac5a7c8f9098d04a8a)